# how to convert python dictionary into required data frame output?

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

lets say I am getting api response as

```
response= {
'id': {'abc':[{'area_code':'mkt','area_name':'market'},{'area_code':'chdi','area_name':'chandani'}],
{'xyz':[{'area_code':'rlr','area_name':'rural'},{'area_code':'rwl_st','area_name':'railway station'}]}
}}
```

I wanted to convert it to data frame as (expected output as)

[image]

my effort :`pd.json_normalize(response).apply(pd.Series.explode)`

but it didn't work

Comment: `response` is not currently a valid python dictionary.

Comment: Don't add the same question two time. Next time fix the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your response must look like this to work:

```py
response = {
   "id":{
      "abc":[
         {
            "area_code":"mkt",
            "area_name":"market"
         },
         {
            "area_code":"chdi",
            "area_name":"chandani"
         }
      ],
      "xyz":[
         {
            "area_code":"rlr",
            "area_name":"rural"
         },
         {
            "area_code":"rwl_st",
            "area_name":"railway station"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

After that, you must create another structure since `json_normalize` works with list of dictionaries and the `id` must be included there:

```py
new_response = [{"id": rid, **r} for rid in response["id"] for r in response["id"][rid]]
```

Finally you just need to apply the function:

```py
final_result = pd.json_normalize(new_response)
```